# How to hold a lock to redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have the following NodeJS code that initialize a list only if the list doesn't exist.

```
if (redisClient.lLen('mylist') === 0) {
    let initialVal = Array(100).fill(-1)
    await redisClient.rPush('mylist', initialVal)
}
```

If the above code is running at the same time by multiple instances, then due to race conditions `await redisClient.rPush('mylist', initialVal)` may run multiple times.

I only want the above code to run once by one of the NodeJS instances to initialize the list.
How can I make the above code an atomic operation?

### Answer

I formatted the answer given by Stephen Jennings (Thank you!)

```
redisClient.EVAL(`
    if redis.call("LLEN", "mylist") == 0
    then
    for i = 1,100,1 do
        redis.call("RPUSH", "mylist", "-1")
    end
    end
`)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Lua script to do the check and inserts atomically.

```
redisClient.EVAL(`
if redis.call(“LLEN”, “mylist”) == 0
  for i = 1,100,1
    redis.call(”RPUSH”, ”mylist”, ”-1”)
  end
end
`)
```

Comment: Sorry if the syntax isn’t quite right, I’m on my phone and can’t look it up easily. Hopefully someone will find and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't fully understand the use case, you might want to look into the [RPUSHX command](https://redis.io/commands/rpushx) as a way to ensure you only add to a list that exists.

Comment: The use case is try to initialize the list only once even if multiple instances of the code are running.